# How to use quasar framework in vuepress 2?

Tags: quasar-framework, vuepress

I'm now using vuepress2 with quasar 2.7.1 like this:

```js
import { Quasar } from 'quasar';

export default defineClientAppEnhance(({ app, router, siteData }) => {
  app.use(Quasar);
}
```

```scss
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined);
@import 'quasar/src/css/variables.sass';
@import 'quasar/src/css/core/colors.sass';
.quasar-comp {
  @import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass';
}
/* I wrap the custome component in class .quasar-comp 
   so that the style from quasar won't conflict with style from vuepress. */
```

but there are 2 issues:

1. The style from quasar cannot works on some components, like `q-btn-dropdown` or `q-menu`.
2. It works well on dev mode(`npm run docs:dev`), but failed to build(`npm run docs:build`).

```bash
✔ Compiling with vite - done
✖ Rendering pages - failed
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
    at installQuasar (/Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.cjs.prod.js:6:15228)
    at Object.install (/Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.cjs.prod.js:6:479348)
    at Object.use (/Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.prod.js:3393:28)
    at /Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/docs/.vuepress/dist/.server/app.js:3745:7
    at createVueApp (/Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/docs/.vuepress/dist/.server/app.js:4177:11)
    at async /Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/vuepress-vite/node_modules/@vuepress/bundler-vite/lib/build/build.js:49:52
    at async /Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/@vuepress/utils/lib/withSpinner.js:12:24
    at async build (/Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/vuepress-vite/node_modules/@vuepress/bundler-vite/lib/build/build.js:34:5)
    at async /Users/lxm/Documents/neo/leaneo-docs/node_modules/@vuepress/cli/lib/commands/build/createBuild.js:51:5
```

Is there a better way to make quasar and vuepress works together?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation in Vuepress 2 (beta) and Quasar with Typescript.

First, install Quasar into Vuepress with the new syntax and import all styles:

`client.ts`:

```
import { defineClientConfig } from "@vuepress/client";
import { Quasar } from "quasar";

import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass';

export default defineClientConfig({
  enhance({app, router, siteData}) {
    app.use(Quasar);
  },
  setup() {},
  rootComponents: [],
});
```

Then, ignore deprecation errors from `sass` if you're using vite.

`config.ts`

```
import { viteBundler } from '@vuepress/bundler-vite'
import { defineUserConfig } from '@vuepress/cli'

export default defineUserConfig({
  // your config
  ...
  
  bundler: viteBundler({
    viteOptions: {
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            sassOptions: {
              // ignore sass deprecation errors
              quietDeps: true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
  }),
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried the solution, but I still got same error when build. 

✔ Compiling with vite - done
✖ Rendering pages - failed
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: and there are still sass deprecation warnings when building.

Comment: Hey @lxmfly123, the second code block in config.ts is the config to ignore SASS errors in vite bundler, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Quasar needs some globales to be defined (ie if it's SSR). My following solution works ONYL on client-side so be sure to wrap your custom-quasar component in `<ClientOnly>` !

```js
// .vuepress/config.ts
bundler: viteBundler({
  viteOptions: {
    define: {
      __QUASAR_VERSION__: `'dev'`,
      __QUASAR_SSR__: false,
      __QUASAR_SSR_SERVER__: false,
      __QUASAR_SSR_CLIENT__: false,
      __QUASAR_SSR_PWA__: false
    }
  }
}),
```

```js
// .vuepress/client.ts
import { defineClientConfig } from '@vuepress/client'
import Quasar from "quasar/src/install-quasar.js";

// optionally import your styles here
// import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass';

export default defineClientConfig({
  enhance({ app, router, siteData }) {
    app.use(Quasar);
  },
  setup() {
  },
  rootComponents: [],
});
```

```markdown
<!-- README.md -->
<ClientOnly>
  <MyComponent />
</ClientOnly>
```